# Is there a way to automatically setup MediaWiki when running with docker compose?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, mediawiki

I'm using MediaWiki with MariaDB, running on Docker version 24.0.2 and Docker Compose version 2.18.1. The default setup works well. Now, I would like to collaborate with a colleague on GitHub, and ideally, they should be able to clone the repository and run `docker compose up` to set everything up. There should already be a `LocalSettings.php` file in the root directory, which will be linked as a volume inside the MediaWiki container.

The problem is that normally, after running `docker compose up`, one needs to manually set up MediaWiki either through the browser or using the `install.php` script. If a `LocalSettings.php` file is detected, the setup is skipped, and it seems that the database is not set up correctly.

When trying to access the Wiki through the browser, we encounter the following error message:

```
Deprecated: Caller from LCStoreDB::get ignored an error originally raised from LCStoreDB::get: [1146] Table 'my_wiki.l10n_cache' doesn't exist in /var/www/html/includes/debug/MWDebug.php on line 381
[3c48d5308eca6dc9224e9901] 2023-05-31 06:58:04: Fatal exception of type Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBQueryError
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue and have MediaWiki running directly after cloning the repository?

Here is my current `docker-compose.yml` file. I have tried running the `update.php` script when starting the MediaWiki container to set up the database, but I encountered the error message `Can not upgrade from versions older than 1.31, please upgrade to that version or later first.` even though it should be using the image version 1.39.3.

```
# MediaWiki with MariaDB
#
# Access via "http://localhost:8080"
#   (or "http://$(docker-machine ip):8080" if using docker-machine)
version: '3'
services:
  mediawiki:
    image: mediawiki:1.39.3
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - database
    volumes:
      - images:/var/www/html/images
      # After initial setup, download LocalSettings.php to the same directory as
      # this yaml and uncomment the following line and use compose to restart
      # the mediawiki service
      - ./LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php
    command: sh -c "php maintenance/update.php"
  # This key also defines the name of the database host used during setup instead of the default "localhost"
  database:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      # @see https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/source/mediawiki/browse/master/includes/DefaultSettings.php
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_wiki
      MYSQL_USER: wikiuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  images:
  db:
```

This is the `LocalSettings.php` file I downloaded after the manual setup:

```
<?php
# This file was automatically generated by the MediaWiki 1.39.3
# installer. If you make manual changes, please keep track in case you
# need to recreate them later.
#
# See docs/Configuration.md for all configurable settings
# and their default values, but don't forget to make changes in _this_
# file, not there.
#
# Further documentation for configuration settings may be found at:
# https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings

# Protect against web entry
if ( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
    exit;
}


## Uncomment this to disable output compression
# $wgDisableOutputCompression = true;

$wgSitename = "HI-LONa";

## The URL base path to the directory containing the wiki;
## defaults for all runtime URL paths are based off of this.
## For more information on customizing the URLs
## (like /w/index.php/Page_title to /wiki/Page_title) please see:
## https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL
$wgScriptPath = "";

## The protocol and server name to use in fully-qualified URLs
$wgServer = "http://localhost:8080";

## The URL path to static resources (images, scripts, etc.)
$wgResourceBasePath = $wgScriptPath;

## The URL paths to the logo.  Make sure you change this from the default,
## or else you'll overwrite your logo when you upgrade!
$wgLogos = [
    '1x' => "$wgResourceBasePath/resources/assets/change-your-logo.svg",
    'icon' => "$wgResourceBasePath/resources/assets/change-your-logo-icon.svg",
];

## UPO means: this is also a user preference option

$wgEnableEmail = true;
$wgEnableUserEmail = true; # UPO

$wgEmergencyContact = "";
$wgPasswordSender = "";

$wgEnotifUserTalk = false; # UPO
$wgEnotifWatchlist = false; # UPO
$wgEmailAuthentication = true;

## Database settings
$wgDBtype = "mysql";
$wgDBserver = "database";
$wgDBname = "my_wiki";
$wgDBuser = "wikiuser";
$wgDBpassword = "example";

# MySQL specific settings
$wgDBprefix = "";

# MySQL table options to use during installation or update
$wgDBTableOptions = "ENGINE=InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARSET=binary";

# Shared database table
# This has no effect unless $wgSharedDB is also set.
$wgSharedTables[] = "actor";

## Shared memory settings
$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_NONE;
$wgMemCachedServers = [];

## To enable image uploads, make sure the 'images' directory
## is writable, then set this to true:
$wgEnableUploads = false;
$wgUseImageMagick = true;
$wgImageMagickConvertCommand = "/usr/bin/convert";

# InstantCommons allows wiki to use images from https://commons.wikimedia.org
$wgUseInstantCommons = false;

# Periodically send a pingback to https://www.mediawiki.org/ with basic data
# about this MediaWiki instance. The Wikimedia Foundation shares this data
# with MediaWiki developers to help guide future development efforts.
$wgPingback = true;

# Site language code, should be one of the list in ./includes/languages/data/Names.php
$wgLanguageCode = "en-gb";

# Time zone
$wgLocaltimezone = "UTC";

## Set $wgCacheDirectory to a writable directory on the web server
## to make your wiki go slightly faster. The directory should not
## be publicly accessible from the web.
#$wgCacheDirectory = "$IP/cache";

$wgSecretKey = "7b136b2940a0158c40955529c9f5e6a7b28c777ef359397a82da99729f48e8c3";

# Changing this will log out all existing sessions.
$wgAuthenticationTokenVersion = "1";

# Site upgrade key. Must be set to a string (default provided) to turn on the
# web installer while LocalSettings.php is in place
$wgUpgradeKey = "3bb56c36c2f9ad8b";

## For attaching licensing metadata to pages, and displaying an
## appropriate copyright notice / icon. GNU Free Documentation
## License and Creative Commons licenses are supported so far.
$wgRightsPage = ""; # Set to the title of a wiki page that describes your license/copyright
$wgRightsUrl = "";
$wgRightsText = "";
$wgRightsIcon = "";

# Path to the GNU diff3 utility. Used for conflict resolution.
$wgDiff3 = "/usr/bin/diff3";

## Default skin: you can change the default skin. Use the internal symbolic
## names, e.g. 'vector' or 'monobook':
$wgDefaultSkin = "vector";

# Enabled skins.
# The following skins were automatically enabled:
wfLoadSkin( 'MinervaNeue' );
wfLoadSkin( 'MonoBook' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Timeless' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Vector' );


# End of automatically generated settings.
# Add more configuration options below.
```

Any help appreaciated! :-)

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Have you found a solution to it in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your database. You have correctly set it up in your docker-compose file, and I guess in your LocalSettings as well. But it would work only on the 'local instance' you used when initializing your wiki (using the install script or by the web browser page).

The thing is, even though you share your stack on GitHub, the actual data for your DB is saved in your volume (db in this case). However, if your colleagues clone the repo, they won't have your data, only the stack. (You would have to share your Docker Volume of your Database)

And you get the following error : `Can not upgrade from versions older than 1.31, please upgrade to that version or later first.` because you are trying to update a database that doesn't exist (well it does, but it doesn't have table).

### How to fix ?

So, if you want to work with your colleagues, you can :

- **Import a backup of your database**
- Use the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`
- **Run your docker on a shared server with your colleagues**.

Otherwise, your stack and Localsettings looks fine.